# In Maven, how do I specify that my parent project has a non-standard pom filename

Tags: maven

I have two products that need to build from a set of projects, so I need to have two parent pom files. I know how to specify an alternate pom for the mvn command to use. What do I put in a child pom.xml to tell it that the parent has a non-standard name?

Answer (score 3):

I found it via the Eclipse POM editor: relativePath

```xml
<parent>
    <relativePath>../oda_pom.xml</relativePath>
    <groupId>xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>yyy</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```